# Add checkboxes in every second row

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range

Below is a section of a Sub which adds rows to a spreadsheet, including checkboxes in every second column.

Every time I try to use a union or complex range it doesn't seem to work for the rngCel2 Dim statement I have.
The top section isn't the part of concern but I've added it for context and just in case some part of it is interfering.

```vb
Sub Addrow()

    Dim rngCel2 As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
    
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    EventNo = LastRow - 3
    
    NewEvent = EventNo + 1
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = NewEvent
    
    If NewEvent Mod 2 = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25)).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23)).Select

    For Each rngCel2 In Selection
        With rngCel2.MergeArea.Cells
            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel2.Address Then
                Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                With ChkBx
                    .Value = xlOff
                    .LinkedCell = rngCel2.MergeArea.Cells.Address
                    With .Border
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCel2
    
    For Each ChkBx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        ChkBx.Caption = ""
    Next ChkBx

End Sub
```

What the code should achieve:
[image]

Each macro use (tied to a button) should add one row beneath the last. There isn't any code to recolour the checkbox columns yet.

I tried selecting the required cells individually. That returns an error code because the code requires a range.
The same issue appears when I try a union function.

I tried finding a 'for every second cell' function or using a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without using select.

Here is my interpretation:

```
Sub Addrow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCel2 As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
    
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        EventNo = lastrow - 4
        NewEvent = EventNo + 1
        .Cells(lastrow, 1) = NewEvent
    
        If NewEvent Mod 2 = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 26)).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
        End If
        
        a = 6                                    'start column
        b = 26                                   'end column
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For x = a To b Step 2                    'step 2 skips to the next
            Set rngCel2 = .Cells(lastrow, x)
            With rngCel2
                Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                With ChkBx
                    .Value = xlOff
                    .LinkedCell = rngCel2.Address
                    With .Border
                    End With
                End With
                .Interior.Color = rgbGrey
            End With
        Next x
    
    
        For Each ChkBx In .CheckBoxes
            ChkBx.Caption = ""
        Next ChkBx
    End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your massive help and clearing up my clunky code. This solution worked perfectly and seeing it in action I think I learned a bit more about how for loops should work. Cheers, Max